# Turn off Snapchat camera sound in Android

Tags: audio, camera, snapchat

Whenever I take a picture with the front camera on Snapchat on my Xiaomi Mi Max 2, it makes a loud fake camera shutter sound.

I have tried putting the phone on mute/do not disturb and having the ringer volume, alarm volume, and media volume off, and it still makes the sound. I have gone into the camera app settings and turned off the camera sounds, which works for my default camera app (I can take pictures on it with no sound) but it still makes the sound on Snapchat.

Does anyone know how to disable this sound? I'd be surprised if Snapchat made its own camera shutter sound which isn't mutable, surely it just uses the device's settings and sounds, right?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Snapchat alpha enabled, turning on flash or night mode will disable the shutter sound.

To enable Snapchat alpha right now in the new update, you have to open the Snapchat map and search Bermuda. You'll find a ghost that can enable alpha mode.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution - just press the moon icon on the top right corner of the screen on Snapchat to turn on Snapchat night mode and leave it on.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of struggle, I found a solution. It might not be a permanent one but for now it works. Just download an older version where the sound is not in the app yet.

Comment: And which version would that be?

Comment: I have removed the link. We don't trust the links from that domain. For others looking for a trustworthy link: you ***may*** consider APK Mirror here: https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/snap-inc/snapchat/#description

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Snapchat will access your mobile camera application because it has the permission given by the developers, one thing you can stop this by the following statements.

Go to Setting - Apps - Snapchat - then click on the launch button - then go to running apps - then just choose Snapchat and select stop. By this, you can stop the service of this app.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the question, which is about "taking a photo" not "stopping the service of this app".

Answer (score -1):

Go to your Camera app → open Settings, and turn off Camera sound. Because Snapchat uses the Xiaomi's Camera, it inherits this setting.

Comment: Snapchat uses the device's camera, but it doesn't use *other camera apps*, and thus those settings won't be inherited.

Answer (score -1):

Snapchat doesn't directly use Xiaomi camera. It takes a screenshot of what happens on the screen through the camera. It doesn't actually take a 'photo'. I read it in an article. Try comparing Snapchat photos with camera photos with Xiaomi phone. The difference is absurd.

Snapchat doesn't want to make so many configurations for every Android phone that is getting pushed out on the market. Different resolutions, screen ratios, camera, etc., so they made a standard for probably all non-flagship phones I think. I got Mi Mix 1, this one is affected by this standard.

Comment: This needs some clarification: Snapchat doesn't use Xiaomi's *Camera* app, but it certainly uses the device's camera. 3rd-party apps can request an image from image-taking apps (such as Camera apps) or integrate camera API directly to their app. Most dedicated Camera apps take better photos because they're developed for that purpose, while other apps may just take a photo simply for convenience. However, this doesn't answer the question of "how to turn off the camera sound while taking a photo on Snapchat"...

Answer (score -1):

It's because of the rear camera.

Switch it to the front camera on your phone so when your app opens, it shows you on the app screen. And now there's no more sound when you open or close your app, as long as you are using the front camera and always set it back to open the front camera on your phone.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the question, which is about "taking a photo" not "opening the app".